# Why IPTV does not work?

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, windows-10-preview, iptv

My provider support IPTV. This service uses SAP for discovery. I have one problem. My playlist is empty.

Furthermore, I try to use some workaround. I have a file **playlist.m3u**, which contains the following rows:

```
#EXTM3U url-tvg="http://iptv.domain.ru/jtv.zip" tvg-shift=0 
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="Title" ,Title
udp://@124.34.10.1:1234
```

If I try to play some channel, I get nothing, I see just black window.

Support says, that maybe firewall blocks VLC. I disable firewall, but nothing changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible reasons why your IPTV playlist is empty or why you are getting a black window when you try to play a channel:

- **Your IPTV provider may be down or having problems.** This is the most
  likely reason for an empty playlist or a black window. You can check
  your IPTV provider's website or social media pages to see if they
  have announced any outages or problems.
- **Your IPTV provider may have changed their M3U playlist URL.** If this
  is the case, you will need to update your M3U playlist URL in your
  IPTV player. You can usually find the M3U playlist URL on your IPTV
  provider's website or in their dashboard.
- **Your IPTV provider may be using a different streaming protocol.** IPTV
  providers use a variety of streaming protocols, including HLS,
  MPEG-TS, and UDP. If your IPTV player does not support the streaming
  protocol that your IPTV provider is using, you will not be able to
  watch the channels.
- **Your firewall or antivirus software may be blocking the IPTV player.**
  Even if you have disabled your firewall, it is possible that your
  antivirus software is still blocking the IPTV player. Try disabling
  your antivirus software temporarily to see if that fixes the problem.
- **There may be a problem with your IPTV player.** Try using a different
  IPTV player to see if that fixes the problem.

Here are some additional troubleshooting tips:

- **Try restarting your streaming device and your router.** Sometimes,
  simply restarting your devices can fix minor problems.
- **Check your internet connection.** Make sure that you have a strong and
  stable internet connection. IPTV apps require a fast internet
  connection in order to stream video smoothly.
- **Try a different IPTV app.** There are many different IPTV apps
  available. Try using a [different IPTV app](https://top10pcsoftware.com/best-iptv-player-for-windows/) to see if that fixes the
  problem.
- **Check your IPTV links.** Make sure that your IPTV links are valid and
  that they are working properly. You can test your IPTV links by using
  a web browser.
- **Contact your IPTV provider.** If you have tried all of the above and
  you are still having problems, contact your IPTV provider for
  support.

Comment: Is this from ChatGPT?